# Genymotion is not working

Tags: 16.04

Suddenly `Genymotion` has stopped working. Now I can't reinstall it. It is showing an error.

```
/genymotion: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1: undefined symbol: drmGetDevice
```

Answer (score 26):

go to the directory where you have installed genymotion and remove libdrm.so.2

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on just how the OP would do this?  What terminal commands he would have to run could be helpful.

Comment: let's say you have installed your genymotion in /opt/genymotion

Comment: now open terminal 'cd /opt/genymotion'   and then type 'sudo rm libdrm.so.2'  and then enter the password and hit enter

Comment: It works, but why?

Comment: Can someone give some explanation about the answer?